# how to sort data with click header datagridview asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

i have data from sql sever and i show it in web. i want sort that data only with click header datagridview. how can i sort that data. thanks

Comment: What code are you using to display it? What have you tried so far? Would you prefer a server side (asp.net) or client side (javascript) solution? Did you try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: my code not bring a change @nick

Comment: in my grid view, there is no properties GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler @nick

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with asp.net or gridview. Can you just add the event handler in?

Comment: i prefer use server side(asp.net)@nick

Comment: The _GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler_ "event handler" (the click event handler on the list view side and the C# server side part). Basically if that link can't help you, I doubt if I can.

Comment: where is that handler.. i not found that @nick

Comment: i using gridview not list view @nick

Comment: The title of the article is: "How to: Sort a GridView Column When a Header Is Clicked". If the control doesn't match, can't you use the same principle: i.e. find some kind of click event property in the header on your control and use it to post back to resort? I really can't help much more

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Table plug-in for jQuery](https://datatables.net/)
It is more flexible, client side control which will perform all the functionality you needed. Plenty of examples are given on stackoverflow and their official website too.